# How can I stop loader file sound in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var loader_2:Loader = new Loader();
loader_2.load(new URLRequest("Mov/pat2/P2_Manu1_sl1.swf"), LC_2);
var LC_2:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false,ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
my_loader_2.addChild(loader_2);

SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

// how can I stop sound in next click. I have used {SoundMixer.stopAll();} this code for stop sound. But I cant stop previous loader file sound.

Answer (score 0):

Via checking [the documentation for `Loader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) you'll find that there is an `unload()` method. This should unload the .swf and thus stop the sound (unless that swf somehow messes with your current `ApplicationDomain`).